# Java 1.4 debug problems "Transport dt_shmem failed to initialize"

Tags: java, windows-8, jdk1.4

I have installed new PC that runs Windows 8 and new NetBeans (7.3.1) IDE and old java 1.4 JDK.

After I tried debugging I got following error:

debug:

```
Transport dt_shmem failed to initialize, rc = 509.
FATAL ERROR in native method: No transports initialized
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Everything works fine in old windows 7 machine. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use Java 7?

Comment: Java 1.4 is [**definitely** not supported on Windows 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-139862.html) and chances are that it won't ever run. The (paid) "JFB" release is supported up to Windows 7, the normal one only supports Windows XP! Java 1.4 is **11 years old!** Stop using it!

Comment: Doesn't NetBeans 7.3.1 require Java 1.5 and above?

Comment: You should be actually happy that it is running in Windows 7 with latest Netbeans because I was not expecting that too...

Comment: @zEro You need Java 1.6 to run NetBeans 7.3 but you can use any Java inside for compiling (this is managed separately).

Comment: @UwePlonus Oh, I'm so totally at loss of words for my hasty remark!